# Error about local variable in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, c#-4.0

ERROR Message:
A local variable named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'e', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else. 
Why I'm seeing this error? How to remove. Please help. I'm new. Happy to see elaborate answer.

```
    protected void ButtonDeleteProfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string inputString;
        inputString = TextBoxInputEmployeeID.Text;
        int inputEmployeeID;
        int.TryParse(inputString, out inputEmployeeID);

        TBL_EMPLOYEE deleteprofile = new TBL_EMPLOYEE();
        TBL_EMPLOYEE_EDUCATION deleteEducation = new TBL_EMPLOYEE_EDUCATION();
        TBL_LEAVEAPPLICATION deleteApplication = new TBL_LEAVEAPPLICATION();
        TBL_LogIn deleteLoginInfo = new TBL_LogIn();
        deleteEducation = hrmsDB.TBL_EMPLOYEE.Where(e => e.EmployeeID==inputEmployeeID).FirstOrDefault();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already got a method parameter called `e`, so you can't introduce a lambda expression parameter called `e`. You'll need to rename one of them.

As a shorter example, to show this has nothing to do with EF etc:

```
// Invalid: same variable name twice
void Foo(string x)
{
    Action<int> action = x => {};
}

// Valid: different variable names
static void Foo(string x)
{
    Action<int> action = y => {};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
protected void ButtonDeleteProfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Conflicts with this line:

```
deleteEducation = hrmsDB.TBL_EMPLOYEE
.Where(e => e.EmployeeID==inputEmployeeID).FirstOrDefault();
```

The `e` is used in the `.Where(e => e.EmployeeID==inputEmployeeID)`

Because you are not using `EventArgs e` in the click event you can easily change it to `EventArgs ev`

So that the click event becomes this:

```
protected void ButtonDeleteProfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs ev)
    {
        string inputString;
        inputString = TextBoxInputEmployeeID.Text;
        int inputEmployeeID;
        int.TryParse(inputString, out inputEmployeeID);

        TBL_EMPLOYEE deleteprofile = new TBL_EMPLOYEE();
        TBL_EMPLOYEE_EDUCATION deleteEducation = new TBL_EMPLOYEE_EDUCATION();
        TBL_LEAVEAPPLICATION deleteApplication = new TBL_LEAVEAPPLICATION();
        TBL_LogIn deleteLoginInfo = new TBL_LogIn();
        deleteEducation = hrmsDB.TBL_EMPLOYEE.Where(e => e.EmployeeID==inputEmployeeID).FirstOrDefault();

    }
```